# Electron js win.webContents.print callback function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am working on an application with Electron js and Vue js. I need to print the Synchronous request sent by Renderer with the print function. According to the result, I have to transmit the result to the renderer over the backend. Therefore, I use the callback function of the print function. But when I use this function, the print method does not work. I shared the codes below. Could there be an error?

```
 ipcMain.on("set-print", function(event, arg) {
let options = {
  silent: true,
  deviceName: arg,
};
win.webContents.print(options, function(success) {
  event.returnValue = success;
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try Promise function

```
win.webContents.print(options)
.then((success)=>{
console.log(success);
})
.catch((err)=>{
console.log(err)
});
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewprintoptions